# .java is not on the classpath of project, only syntax errors are reported

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, classpath

I could not find a proper answer to this error in other posts. 
I am using Maven for building my project in VS Code and whenever I create a class this error appears. 
Do I need to do anything with .classpath file? 
Correct me if I am mistaken, this error is pointing out that the class is not recognized by the .classpath file in which it belongs to, so I have to address it in that file.

Tnx

Comment: In my case, I do not have this error message if I create a .java file in my first Java program folder in this Workspace of VScode. Otherwise, creating .java files in other folders under this Workspace leads to this error message. Using Ubuntu 16.04, Oracle JDK-15

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.

From Welcome screen, go to Student-->Getting Started-->FAQ-->Find the "Why do I see tons of problems and red squiggles?" portion and click " Clean Workspace". That fixed my problem.

Comment: Thank you!! That fixed it for me as well.

Comment: from the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) type "Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace"

Answer (score 5):

It seems like no one else knew it!

The problem was regarding "folder convention" and "maven-dependency-plugin".
As I created my Maven project with the line below via windows command line, maven did not install dependency-plugin and that created the first problem.

Second, what I meant by "folder convention" was, deleting "java" folder which is created by executing bellow Maven command line, caused me a problem since Maven compiler does not find any Java project to go to and execute codes. Deleting Java folder will also lead to the error above because no Java file is recognized, so no java files will be added to .classpath folder respectively.

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=*name* -DartifactId=*name*  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem.
Just close the vscode and open it again.
Hope it works

Comment: This also worked for me, but make sure you close all instances of VSCode before re-opening.

Comment: or just reload vscode window by CTRL + SHIFT + p, and search 'reload window' and hit enter.

Answer (score 3):

Since i was using a different structure from what the maven project expected i had to manually change the `.classpath` file from pointing to the wrong folder. Only after this that my imports started to be correctly resolved.

Original:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    ...
```

Modified `path` attribute:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was just about folder structure of `vscode`. when you created java file, it would have created a `.java` file (and maybe a `.class` file). Just simply move the `.java` file into `src` folder and `.class` file into `bin` folder and the problem is solved.

[link of screenshot if you need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y55Cv.png)

Answer (score 0):

i have noticed when i open multiple cmd to type "code . "  this error occurs
try to close all CMD's and  reopen project  i think it will go away

Answer (score 0):

Simply create your files inside the src folder your problem will be solved.

" If you already created them outside the src folder move them into src folder"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For vscode users:

1. open new empty vscode window
2. on the explorer section you will get this "Create Java Project" button.
   [image]

3. you will get many options. choose No build tools for basic template.